# Replacement or repair to the wheels of Sliding doors?

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I am trying to find replacements or find some DIY solution to replace the wheels, the original parts are manufactured by Komandor. I am unable to fin replacements in local stores. The width of the sliding wheel mechanism is about 4cm for one door.

**Where can I find replacements or DIY solution to the wheels of the sliding doors?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Find or make new wheels.

Comment: Have you checked with the door manufacturer to see if they can sell you new wheels and/or a complete wheel mount (i.e. that entire silver piece in the first pic)? And, what does "worn out" mean? Are they a bit wobbly & sticky, do the wheels flat refuse to spin? With some additional detail, there may be a way to fix instead of replace.

Comment: @FreeMan Komandor is the manufactur, cannot find the replacements locally.

Comment: I don't know where "locally" is, but they have a web site. You may have to hit the "contact" link (top right on the Canada version of the site - don't ask why I picked that one, I just did...) and ask them where to find them or if you can order direct. Based on the additional pic, it looks like the wheels are riveted into place, and, unless you have machining tools and experience, replacing just the wheels may prove to be a tad difficult. Sometimes, "replace" is just more time and cost effective than "repair".

Comment: It was super hard to find Komandor parts but I found a shop Lasimyynti Tammela that sells Komandor parts, parts replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had issues finding wheels because the MFG went out of business. I found other sets that did not fit but I was able to use the wheel itself by drilling and grinding to remove the damaged wheel on my original hardware and install the wheel from a new piece using a 4-40 screw as the axle since it was ruined on removal, I don’t know how long it lasted as that house was sold a year or so later but it worked and the adjustment still worked a Dremel tool was really handy on that fix.

Comment: The mfg is most definitely still in business - OP listed the manufacturer and I just checked their web site. They don't have repair parts listed, but they do have a "Contact Us".

Comment: The op has a bunch of parts and could also do what I did when the MFG was no longer in business some models not made also don’t have parts available any longer even if the mfg is in business. My answer was a solution that worked and could work for the op.

Comment: indeed. I'd suggest contacting the mfg as a first try. Just wanted to point that out.